# Kunena - how to change Site name in browser page

Tags: browser, joomla2.5, title, forum

Hello I am using Kunena 3.0.4 and I want to change my forum titles in the browser page.

Now they are

Category Index- Forum Name- site name
or
topic name-forum name-site name

And I want to make them

Topic name-site name

Where can I change this?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to debug this exact same issue and I found your post. Luckily, I figured out how to do this with some head scratching, Googling and searching the Kunena source files. So here is an answer, in case you haven't already figured it out.

There are two things that need to be done: Editing the `setTitle()` function and editing the language file for the Kunena component. The function can be found in the `view.php` file present in the following folder for Kunena 3.0.5 (the latest version as of May 21, 2014):

```
YOUR_ROOT_DIR/public_html/libraries/kunena/view.php
```

Then, edit the function `setTitle()` to your heart's content. Play around with it to give you the look and feel you are going for. Here is the default function:

```
public function setTitle($title) {
    if (!$this->state->get('embedded')) {
        // Check for empty title and add site name if param is set
        $title = strip_tags($title);
        if ($this->app->getCfg('sitename_pagetitles', 0) == 1) {
            $title = JText::sprintf('JPAGETITLE', $this->app->getCfg('sitename'), $this->config->board_title .' - '. $title);
        } elseif ($this->app->getCfg('sitename_pagetitles', 0) == 2) {
            $title = JText::sprintf('JPAGETITLE', $title .' - '. $this->config->board_title, $this->app->getCfg('sitename'));
        } else {
            // TODO: allow translations/overrides (also above)
            $title = KunenaFactory::getConfig()->board_title .' :: '. $title;
        }
        $this->document->setTitle($title);
    }
}
```

Now, the lines that need to be edited are in the `if-elseif-else` clause. Notice the hypen '-', being added via concatenation. For me, I had to edit the `elseif` part. The `sprintf` function needs two arguments apart from the 'JPAGETITLE'. The first argument here is `$title .' - '. $this->config->board_title` which is the title variable plus the forum title as set in Kunena. The second argument is `$this->app->getCfg('sitename')`, which is your site name. There will be an additional hypen between argument 1 and 2. So if we have the following scenario:

```
$title = 'Random Page';
$this->config->board_title = 'Kunena Forums';
$this->app->getCfg('sitename') = 'Joomla Site';
```

You will get the output, based on this code:

```
Random Page - Kunena Forums - Joomla Site
```

I have instead modified this function to:

```
public function setTitle($title) {
    if (!$this->state->get('embedded')) {
        // Check for empty title and add site name if param is set
        $title = strip_tags($title);
        if ($this->app->getCfg('sitename_pagetitles', 0) == 1) {
            $title = JText::sprintf('JPAGETITLE', $this->app->getCfg('sitename'), $this->config->board_title, $title);
        } elseif ($this->app->getCfg('sitename_pagetitles', 0) == 2) {
            $title = JText::sprintf('JPAGETITLE',  $title, $this->config->board_title);//, $this->app->getCfg('sitename'));
        } else {
            // TODO: allow translations/overrides (also above)
            $title = KunenaFactory::getConfig()->board_title .' :: '. $title;
        }
        $this->document->setTitle($title);
    }
}
```

So, the same example will give me:

```
Random Page - Kunena Forums
```

Further, you can change the default text that shows up on the Index page of the forums, i.e. "Category Index" to something nicer. To do that, you need to edit the language file at:

```
YOUR_ROOT_DIR/public_html/components/com_kunena/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_kunena.views.ini
```

Here, look for the tags:

```
COM_KUNENA_VIEW_CATEGORY_DEFAULT="Topics in %s"    
COM_KUNENA_VIEW_TOPICS_DEFAULT="Topic: %s"    
COM_KUNENA_VIEW_CATEGORIES_DEFAULT="Category Index"
```

Change the text to something better. For instance, I totally removed "Topic:" and "Topics in" and replaced "Category Index" with "Forums Home". So, now on my forums main page, I see

```
Forums Home - My Website Forums
```

Edit other strings in the language file to your liking and play around with the `setTitle` function.

In your case, as you want to remove the forum name, remove the `$this->config->board_title` part in the sprintf.

Comment: Great , thanks. I will test it these days and will let you now ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla you can set the page title using document class.

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->setTitle("This is my page title");
```

for more reading about [How to set meta details of Joomla page](http://www.walkswithme.net/how-to-set-meta-data-of-a-page-in-joomla)

Hope its helps..

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I know how to set them in Joomla. The problem is that I don't know where to make the changes in Kunena and to receive browser title as I wrote : topic name - site name

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kunena , but with this option you can edit the component view file and achieve this, also if you're using overriding then can fix without core edit.

Comment: I know how to insert page title, but as I wrote in Kunena I don't know where to make this changes. I just search someone to point me in which files I must look for the change